# PHP export to CSV - Doesnt Export newest Data

Tags: php, sql, csv

I have spent the past 5 or so hours searching forums and the internet for an answer to this issue.

Basically, I have a webpage where a table is generated using data collected from the Oracle SQL Server.

When the page loads, the table shows with the past 7 days worth of data. I have a date selection field with a "Go" button and an "Export to CSV"  button.

If I click the Export button it prompts be to save or open. The CSV is fine it has the correct Data etc etc.

The issue is, when I select a date using the date selection field and hit go... the Table on the page refreshes showing me the data for the specific day. If I then click Export to CSV, the data seems to still be the original Data from when the page first loaded.

This is my code...
I am sorry if the code isn't very great I am a complete novice to php.

```
if(isset($_POST['csv'])) $csv_request=$_POST['csv']; else $csv_request="";  
if(isset($_POST['datepicker'])) $date_filter=$_POST['datepicker']; else $date_filter="";

$output_csv = "";
$chosenDate = $date_filter;

if($chosenDate== "" || $chosenDate == Null){
        $mywhere = 'where timestamp >= trunc(sysdate)-7';
    }
    elseif ($chosenDate=='datepicker'){
            $date_chosen = $_POST['datePicker'];
            $mywhere = "where timestamp like to_date('$date_chosen', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
    }


        $sql =  "Select to_char(timestamp, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi') timestamp, site, sum(Manual_coos) Manual_COOS,Sum(Faulty_COOS) Faulty_COOS, bearer from t_ca_Processed
                    ".$mywhere."
                    AND bearer = '4G'
                    AND faulty_coos = 1
                    group by timestamp, site, Manual_coos, Faulty_COOS, bearer
                UNION ALL
                Select to_char(timestamp, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi') timestamp, site, sum(Manual_coos) Manual_COOS,Sum(Faulty_COOS) Faulty_COOS, bearer from t_ca_Processed
                    ".$mywhere."
                    AND bearer = '4G'
                    AND Manual_coos = 1
                    group by timestamp, site, Manual_coos, Faulty_COOS, bearer
                Order by timestamp ASC";



            $st = $db->execute($sql);

        $output = "<table class = 'sortable' border = 1 Align = 'Center'>
                        <tr style = 'background-color: #f00;'>
                            <th>TimeStamp</th>
                            <th>Site</th>
                            <th>Manual COOS Total</th>
                            <th>Faulty COOS Total</th>
                            <th>Bearer</th>
                        </tr>";

        $output_csv = "TimeStamp,Site,Manual COOS Total,Faulty COOS Total,Bearer\n";
        $counter = 0;

        while (($row = oci_fetch_row($st)) != false)
            {
                    $output .= "<tr";

                    $output .= "><td>$row[0]</td>
                        <td align=center>$row[1]</td>
                        <td align=center>$row[2]</td>
                        <td align=center>$row[3]</td>
                        <td align=center>$row[4]</td></tr>\n";

                    $output_csv .= "$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4]\n";
                    $counter ++;
            }
        $output .= "</table>";
        unset($db);

    If ($csv_request=='csv'){

        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$File_name.".csv\";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        echo $output_csv;
    }
    else
    {
```

This is my HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
        background: #DDDDDD;
        }
        table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
        background: #ccfffff;
        }
    </style>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="/common/javascript/kpc_sorttable2.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/common/flot/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/jquery/ui/1.10.2/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Common/jQuery/ui/1.10.2/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Common/jQuery/ui/1.10.2/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Common/jQuery/ui/1.10.2/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <link rel= 'stylesheet' type=text/css href='/common/style.css'>
        <script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                    })
                })
        </script>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php   generateHeader($menu,'4G Cells Down',1); ?>
        <div class='whitebox'>
        <form method='post' action="" name="parameters" id="parameters">
            <input type='hidden' name='csv' value='csv'>
            <input type='submit' value="Export as CSV" style="float: right;">
        </form>
        <form method='post' action="" name="parameters1" id="parameters1">
            <h3>Last Refreshed <?= $page_load_time ?></h3>
            <input type='hidden' name='datepicker' value='datepicker'>
            <h3>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datePicker"><input type='submit' value="Go"></h3>
            <p><?= $output ?><p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
            generateFooter();
        ?>
    </body>
</html> 
<?php } ?>
```

when I echo $output_csv I always see the newest data set... however the CSV is always the original Data. I have tried to Echo the CSV and I get an error saying headers have already been sent...

I am wondering if when the page originally loads, the csv has been created and only gets prompted to download once I hit the export button and when I have the new data, the file cannot be re-written?

Again sorry if im not very clear, new to this :)

cheers
Mike

Comment: Your CSV will be cached by the browser. To test this do CTRL+F5 to do a hard refresh of the page then try to download your CSV. If its correct then your out of date info is cached. To fix this just append the time to the file name so the browser doesnt think its the same file and re-downloads.

Comment: Tried to Crtl+F5 but no luck still the original data. Thanks though.

Comment: Then perhaps your issue is further up the pipe

Answer (score 0):

Your file probably gets cached by the webserver.
If you add a Cache buster and/or cache header it should work.

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

More info about the PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, including caching directives.

If you generate a unique filename for each change or request, it will also be seen as a new file and caching will be disabled.

```
# Generate a unique name for each request
$File_name = uniqid($File_name . "_");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$File_name.".csv\";");
```

See PHP function [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) for more specifics about the functionality.

Comment: Hi moorscode i did try the cache control header but it still didnt work and i also put in the expires header but again that didnt work either. i will however try the uniqid  and add back in the other headers thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you search for a date, the page refresh and the form refresh too, so when you click on the export csv the "request" is to get the default view. Keep your form (selected data) updated with the current view.

The value of this

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datePicker">
```

have to been keep always with the current view

Comment: I added in extra code to make the Value of the Input stay as what was chosen... but it still doesn't work